# Amplitude Calibration for Pulse Amplitude Modulated (PAM) Infrared (IR) Link with Relative Motion Between Emitter and Receiver

Tags: infrared, amplitude-modulation

I have a project on the drawing board that requires information from some sensors to be passed from a rotating platform via IR link.

This is basically going to be inside the generator next to the windings and I was worried about RF interference and the changing magnetic fields so I thought that going with IR would be better than RF.

The distance between emitter and receiver should be no more than 20 cm (it could be low as 10cm, depending on the mechanics of the generator, but I'm being conservative).

The bandwidth requirements (0.8 Mbps average rate per data channel, with possibly 3-4 data channels) necessitate some method of modulation that allow more bits per symbol.

I was considering PAM but it seems that one issue is how to calibrate for the change in brightness as the transmitter moves toward and away from the receiver. It doesn't seem I can use a reference calibration pulse at the beginning of the transmission since the distance between transmitter and receiver distance vary the entire transmission.

How is this normally handled? Is it just not possible with this PAM?

Comment: What is your distance BW product? MHz-m? or Mbps-m?  Then worst case path loss with motion, angle error. One needs to know SNR, BER and error detection/correction method for proper design

Comment: If you're doing 4-PAM (for example) you just need to use some code that (more or less) guarantees 0 and 3 occur with some minimum frequency, and AGC in your receiver. Probably some basic scrambling to generate a (nearly) uniform distribution of codes would work as well. This assuming the rotation rate is much slower than the data baud rate.

Comment: Some limits on the required bit rate, the rotation rate and the relative received power between the near and far positions would probably be helpful.

Comment: They have 16Mbps-m chips for line of sight but if you need an omni-directional emitter, then you better go with RF unless only only need 100kbps-m product

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I don't think RF is going to work here because too much interference (It's sitting on a motor armature).

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 If I work with one emitter, my transmission window is small enough such that I would require a bit rate of 7.2MHz. Therefore, I was going to use a ring of emitters so at least one would always be visible. That would push the bit rate down to 800kbps. The distance should be no more than 20cm and could be as low as 10cm (depending on the mechanics of the surrounding generator).

Comment: The issue, is that baud rate is for one sensor, and it's been indicated that more than one are probably going to be required. The lead was vague so far but the number seems to be around 4 which increases the bit rate by that many times.

Comment: FSK, (basically FM binary), would be much more immune to noise and changes in signal amplitude.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a discrete ring of IR emitters and possibly this IR Rx, but you don't have enough system specs to choose anything yet.

https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/vishay-semiconductor-opto-division/TFDU8108-TR3/751-1087-2-ND/1681221

But these are rapidly going or are obsolete.

A bigger picture of the actual measurement problem might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I've run into that component too. And yes, I was going to use a ring because I don't want to have to try and get a 7.2MHz baud rate system working. A ring would let me get away with 800kbps. The research lead basically wants to measure the current on the "DC winding" of a generator.

Comment: If Sharp doesn't make it , no one else does. Vishay bought the license and even they are giving up. Insufficient demand. AM on optical is bad news as the AGC is too slow.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was going to use discrete LEDs and photodiodes The communication link only has to be one way. This application does not have to be eye-safe. So you're basically saying I should go with something else like PPM? or PWM?

Comment: Why can't you use PM-VHF with a longitudinal  rotating  wire antenna?

Comment: Honestly, one major factor in that is because I am not an RF engineer. I'm also under the impression that the magnetic fields in the vicinity might mess around with RF more than optical since it's going to be basically inside the generator. I could be wrong though. Do you think I could get away with sticking a Zigbee module with an antenna like that?

Comment: Optical is great if the AM Noise is lower f than your frame rate. Which is not your situation.  But RF -PM is great when there is significant AM within the burst.

Comment: Back in the 90's we used 928MHz binary AM inside a spinning Power Meter for 2 way meter reading.  The only problem was really old Westinghouse meters used a type of plastic on the magnetic air-bearing needle/disk that modulated the RF once per rev.  I found that root cause a few months after the RF PhD's and Eng Mgr gave up. I was just the Ops Mgr. The signal was unreadable until we scraped out the Delrin plastic. Our hybrid design was inserted under the nameplate to read a stripe off the disk and read any time of day by cmd for a million units sharing 1 channel

Comment: For R&D just calibrate a VCO with current sense and use FM. Hopefully the motor doesn't arc much in that FM/VHF/UHF band

Comment: I will consider it. Why was the delrin messing around with things? Can you describe more about what was going on there? I didn't really follow your description of the hybrid solution since I don't know what how the Power Meter was supposed to work in the first place.

Comment: The alum. rotating disk was interfering with RF waves by modulating capacitance of disk and thus amplitude of signal from nearby antenna.  Automated Meter Reading here was all analog with digital radio using AM binary at 928MHz in short bursts. It also worked except 1 of 30 or so different analog power meters. It was also the only 2 way network to work in real time on demand to the headend database.  The Delrin was a tiny problem like your multiple emitters rotating with AM

Answer (score 1):

Forget about PAM. 800 kbps is easily handled with simple binary modulation, using multiple emitters and/or multiple detectors.